# Problemas ao criar itens de um submenu dropdownmenu usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Tenho um dropdownmenu que funciona normalmente quando o carrego usando o asp.net core + razor. Dentro dele tenho os submenus Telefones e WEB... Quando tento recriar os submenus devido a uma necessidade da app, seus itens ficam posicionados fora do submenu, diferentemente de quando é carregado usando o razor do asp.net (Observem os telefones).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O correto deveria ser assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Script JS que recarrega os submenus (Comentei a parte que carrega os itens do submenu WEB):

```
function load_elements_dropdowns() {
    //Carregar Listas
    var selectAdicionarFormaContato = $('#btn-add-contato');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/getFormaContatoList",
        type: "POST",
        data: { pessoaNatureza: $('#pessoaNatureza').val() },
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            selectAdicionarFormaContato.empty();
            selectAdicionarFormaContato.append($('<div class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">Telefones</a><div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">'));
            $.each(data, function () {
                $.each(this, function (i, item) {
                    switch (item.id) {
                        case 1:
                            selectAdicionarFormaContato.append($('<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="' + item.id + '"><i class="icon fa-tty" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + item.descricao + '</a>'));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            selectAdicionarFormaContato.append($('<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="' + item.id + '"><i class="icon wb-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + item.descricao + '</a>'));
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            selectAdicionarFormaContato.append($('<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="' + item.id + '"><i class="icon wb-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + item.descricao + '</a>'));
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            selectAdicionarFormaContato.append($('<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="' + item.id + '"><i class="icon md-headset-mic" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + item.descricao + '</a>'));
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });

            selectAdicionarFormaContato.append($('</div></div><div class="dropdown-divider"></div>'));
            selectAdicionarFormaContato.append($('<div class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">WEB</a><div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">'));


            //$.each(data, function () {
            //    $.each(this, function (i, item) {
            //        //select.append($('1'));
            //        switch (item.id) {
            //            case '5':
            //                console.log('Oranges are $0.59 a pound.');
            //                break;
            //            case '6':
            //                break;
            //            case '7':
            //                break;
            //        }
            //    });
            //});

            selectAdicionarFormaContato.append($('</div></div>'));


        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
        }
    });


}
```

Código do completo do dropdownmenu no asp.net core

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"
            aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="icon wb-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Novo Contato
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="exampleDefaultDropdownSubMenu" role="menu" id="btn-add-contato">
        <div class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">Telefones</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                @if (Model.FormasContato != null)
                {
                    @foreach (var item in Model.FormasContato)
                    {
                        switch (item.Value)
                        {
                            case "1":
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="@item.Value"><i class="icon fa-tty" aria-hidden="true"></i>@item.Text</a>
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="@item.Value"><i class="icon wb-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>@item.Text</a>
                                break;
                            case "3":
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="@item.Value"><i class="icon wb-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>@item.Text</a>
                                break;
                            case "4":
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="@item.Value"><i class="icon md-headset-mic" aria-hidden="true"></i>@item.Text</a>
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">WEB</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                @if (Model.FormasContato != null)
                {
                    @foreach (var item in Model.FormasContato)
                    {
                        switch (item.Value)
                        {
                            case "5":
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="@item.Value"><i class="icon wb-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>@item.Text</a>
                                break;
                            case "6":
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="@item.Value"><i class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>@item.Text</a>
                                break;
                            case "7":
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="@item.Value"><i class="icon fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>@item.Text</a>
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como resolver esse problema? Onde estou errando?
Um abraço a todos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está construindo o HTML de forma errada usando `.append`. Quando você faz append de uma div aberta, o navegador automaticamente fecha a div.

Por exemplo, nesta linha:

```
selectAdicionarFormaContato.append($('<div class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">Telefones</a><div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">'));
```

Você está abrindo duas divs e fazendo o append. O navegador irá fechar essas duas divs assim que fizer o append, fazendo com que o resultado seja diferente do que deseja.

Os fechamentos das divs na linha abaixo serão ignorados:

```
selectAdicionarFormaContato.append($('</div></div><div class="dropdown-divider"></div>'));
```

O que você precisa fazer é montar o HTML numa variável vazia qualquer (no exemplo abaixo, usei `var html= '';`) e ir concatenando as partes do HTML e só no final fazer o append de tudo de uma vez:

```
function load_elements_dropdowns() {
    //Carregar Listas
    var selectAdicionarFormaContato = $('#btn-add-contato');
   var html = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: "/pessoa-gerenciar/getFormaContatoList",
        type: "POST",
        data: { pessoaNatureza: $('#pessoaNatureza').val() },
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            selectAdicionarFormaContato.empty();
            html +=  '<div class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">Telefones</a><div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';
            $.each(data, function () {
                $.each(this, function (i, item) {
                    switch (item.id) {
                        case 1:
                            html += '<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="' + item.id + '"><i class="icon fa-tty" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + item.descricao + '</a>';
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            html += '<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="' + item.id + '"><i class="icon wb-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + item.descricao + '</a>';
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            html += '<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="' + item.id + '"><i class="icon wb-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + item.descricao + '</a>';
                            break;

                        case 4:
                            html += '<a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" data-id="' + item.id + '"><i class="icon md-headset-mic" aria-hidden="true"></i>' + item.descricao + '</a>';
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });

            html += '</div></div><div class="dropdown-divider"></div>';
            html += '<div class="dropdown-submenu"><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">WEB</a><div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';


            //$.each(data, function () {
            //    $.each(this, function (i, item) {
            //        //select.append($('1'));
            //        switch (item.id) {
            //            case '5':
            //                console.log('Oranges are $0.59 a pound.');
            //                break;
            //            case '6':
            //                break;
            //            case '7':
            //                break;
            //        }
            //    });
            //});

            html += '</div></div>';
            selectAdicionarFormaContato.append(html);

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Oops! Algo deu errado.");
        }
    });


}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ótima explicação @Sam!!! :)